# ORACLE SQL "ADD DATE BTW SEVERAL MONTHS

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How I will be able to select Date between01JAN2020 and 30 MAY 2020 on the below code?
The below code is for extraction of sales register in oracle, I would like to be able to add on the code a date between ) 01 JAN 2020 and 30 MAY 2020. Any advice on how to handle it?

```
 select distinct 1
,h.trx_number, h.trx_date, bat.name source_name, P.PARTY_NAME,ha.SALES_CHANNEL_CODE
,(select     NVL(jrret.source_name, jrret.resource_name) 
 from  jtf_rs_resource_extns_vl jrret
 where 1=1
  AND jrret.resource_id = rsa.resource_id)  Sales_person_NAME -----RSA.NAME putting comments on 14- 
 nov-2019 
,msib.inventory_item_id,
T.NAME TNAME,OL.LINE_ID,OL.ORDERED_ITEM,ORG.ORGANIZATION_NAME,msib.secondary_uom_code,
l.description,l.customer_trx_line_id,h.invoice_currency_code,L.extended_amount,
h.exchange_rate,NVL(l.quantity_invoiced,NVL(QUANTITY_CREDITED,0)) QUANTITY,
L.UOM_CODE,L.UNIT_SELLING_PRICE PRICE,
case when l.extended_amount=(l.extended_amount*nvl(h.exchange_rate,1)) then 0 else l.extended_amount 
end Entered_Amount,
(l.extended_amount*nvl(h.exchange_rate,1))Accounted_amount
FROM
RA_CUSTOMER_TRX_ALL H
,RA_CUSTOMER_TRX_LINES_ALL L
,OE_ORDER_LINES_ALL OL
,ORG_ORGANIZATION_DEFINITIONS ORG
,ra_batch_sources_all bat
,mtl_system_items_b msib
, MTL_UOM_CLASS_CONVERSIONS b
,HZ_PARTIES P
,HZ_CUST_ACCOUNTS_ALL HA
,RA_CUST_TRX_TYPES_ALL T,
OE_ORDER_HEADERS_ALL OOHA,
RA_SALESREPS_ALL RSA
WHERE 1=1
AND  OL.SALESREP_ID=RSA.SALESREP_ID(+)
AND L.LINE_TYPE = 'LINE'
AND L.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID = H.CUSTOMER_TRX_ID
AND L.INTERFACE_LINE_ATTRIBUTE6 = OL.LINE_ID
and msib.inventory_item_id=b.inventory_item_id(+)
AND ORG.ORGANIZATION_ID = OL.SHIP_FROM_ORG_ID
and bat.batch_source_id = h.batch_source_id
AND P.PARTY_ID = HA.PARTY_ID
and msib.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID=OL.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
and msib.organization_id = OL.SHIP_FROM_ORG_ID
AND H.BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ID =  CUST_ACCOUNT_ID
and L.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID NOT IN(44717,44723,47722)
AND H.CUST_TRX_TYPE_ID = T.CUST_TRX_TYPE_ID
AND OOHA.HEADER_ID = OL.HEADER_ID
AND OOHA.ORG_ID = OL.ORG_ID
--and H.trx_number='20600200563'
order by trx_date,trx_number
```

Comment: @ Paul Mugambi do you want the date of 30th may to be included in the results? And do you have in the trg_date the time part too? if yes, then the code proposed by @Kumar needs to be slightly adjusted to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

Add below code before `order by trx_date,trx_number`

First option

```
 H.TRX_DATE >= TO_DATE('01JAN2020','DDMONYYYY') AND H.TRX_DATE <=TO_DATE('30MAY2020','DDMONYYYY');
 or
 H.TRX_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('01JAN2020','DDMONYYYY') AND TO_DATE('30MAY2020','DDMONYYYY');
```

Second Option

Set session level date format

```
 ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DDMONYYYY';

 AND H.TRX_DATE BETWEEN '01JAN2020' AND '30MAY2020'
    or
 AND H.TRX_DATE>='01JAN2020' AND H.TRX_DATE<='30MAY2020'
```

Comment: Thank you... Very much sir...All the above options work well

Comment: If the answer provided by @Kumar resolved your issue please accept that answer. Do not leave the question as still active when an acceptable answer has been provided.